# Capturar datos con Google People API

Tags: javascript, api, google-api

Cordial saludo
Deseo poder capturar datos como lo son los basicos (nombre, apellido, correo..) y otros mas específicos como la fecha de cumpleaños y el genero; esto atravez de un boton de inicio de sesión. Todo bien con los datos basicos (Coloco codigo mas adelante). Pero no se como capturar los datos de fecha de cumpleaños y genero. Indagando me tope con que lo puedo hacer con Google People API. Pero soy nuevo en esto de las API y la verdad no logro entender como capturar las variables por este medio.

Con esto he podido capturar los datos basicos

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  <script>
  var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
          var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
          document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
              profile.getName();
        }, function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: primero que todo no debes colocar la tu llave cuando preguntas, ahora bien
mira la documentación `https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing` , ahí estan todos los metodos, solo tienes que usar el adecuado para obtener los datos. mira esta respuesta `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612357/retrieving-date-of-birth-and-marital-status-with-google-oauth-api` también encontré que por seguridad google solo te dará el día de cumpleaños.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo quite. Ya habia observado esto, pero si es posible algun ejemplo donde me pueda guiar sera de gran ayuda

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: @fredyfx deje el proyecto quieto, pero seria bueno que pudieras dar una solucion para un futuro tanto mio como el de toda la comunidad.